# Jackson ignoring @JsonIgnore?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, serialization, jackson

I have a class with a 'read-only' function that shouldn't get serialized into a JSON object. Because the function's name starts with "get", Jackson grabs it, and does not seem to respect the attached `@JsonIgnore` tag:

```
import org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonIgnore;

public class MyClass {

    publicMyClass() {}

    @JsonIgnore
    public String getSomeValue() {return "";}
}
```

I also tried using the following syntax:

```
import org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonIgnoreProperties;

@JsonIgnoreProperties({"someValue"})
public class MyClass {

    publicMyClass() {}

    public String getSomeValue() {return "";}
}
```

In either case the resultant JSON output is the same:

```
{someValue:""}
```

(We're using Jackson 1.9.13 with Spring MVC.)

Other than renaming the function to start with something other than "get", what can I do to prevent Jackson from serializing this function's output?

Comment: I bet your Spring configuration is either using Gson or Jackson 2 to serialize your values.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis How can I find out what the serializer is, do you know?

Comment: For one, you can check your runtime classpath. If it contains both Jackson 2 and Jackson 1, it will use Jackson 2 (which doesn't look at Jackson 1 annotations). Second, do you explicitly set `HttpMessageConverter`s or have the defaults?

Comment: To add to @SotiriosDelimanolis's point, if you have `com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore` available in your path that is another way to tell.

Comment: And you need Jackson 2.1+ as of Spring Framework 4.1 https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/wiki/Migrating-from-earlier-versions-of-the-Spring-Framework#libraries

Comment: Thanks a lot for the feedback folks, you were right: I needed to use the `com.fasterxml.jackson` annotation instead.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Turns out we were using Jackson 2 to for JSON serialization, so I needed to change the annotation package location.

**Jackson 1:**

```
import com.codehaus.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore
```

**Jackson 2:**

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore
```

With the `fasterxml` import everything works as expected.